# Upon clicking a button, how can I input the text from the button into an alert? (And how to disable and leave buttons selected)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to program a mood app where you can pick between buttons of "happy" "sad" etc. Upon clicking on one, I want the information on the text display of the button to go into a function, `saveData`, where I can then display it as an alert. (For example, if I click happy and then click the submit button not shown the alert will display "mood: happy"). How can I do that? I also would like to ask about disabling buttons. For example, after selecting the `happy` button, I want to disable `sad` and `angry` and leave `happy` selected.

```
export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      mood: '',
    }
  }

  saveData = () => {
    const {mood} = this.state;
    alert("mood:", mood);
  };

  render() {
    return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.mood}>Mood</Text>
            <View style={styles.container2}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={mood => this.setState({mood})}
            >
             <Text style={styles.answer}>happy</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={mood=>this.setState({mood})}
            >
             <Text style={styles.answer}>sad</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={mood=>this.setState({mood})}
            >
             <Text style={styles.answer}>angry</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this a react application or react native application, I am confused as I see <View /> and <TouchableOpacity /> components!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you need to pass the correct mood to the function, but `TouchableOpacity` does not know, what mood is selected, so try it like this:

```
export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      mood: '',
    }
  }

  saveData = () => {
    const {mood} = this.state;
    alert("mood:", mood);
  };

  render() {
    const currentMood = this.state.mood;
    return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.mood}>Mood</Text>
            <View style={styles.container2}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              disabled={currentMood.length !== 0 && currentMood !== 'happy'}
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={() => this.setState({mood: "happy"})}
            >
             <Text style={styles.answer}>happy</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              disabled={currentMood.length !== 0 && currentMood !== 'sad'}
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={() => this.setState({mood: "sad"})}
            >
             <Text style={styles.answer}>sad</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              disabled={currentMood.length !== 0 && currentMood !== 'angry'}
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={() => this.setState({mood: "angry"})}
            >
             <Text style={styles.answer}>angry</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

As you can see, you can just pass disable to the TouchableOpacity as well like this.
This will disable the buttons, if a mood is selected but it differs from the current one.

You can also improve it by making it more generic:

```
function App = () => {
    const [currentMood, setMood] = React.useState('');
    const moods = ['happy', 'angry', 'sad'];
    return <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.mood}>Mood</Text>
        <View style={styles.container2}>
        {
           moods.map(mood => <TouchableOpacity
               disabled={currentMood.length !== 0 && currentMood !== mood}
               style={styles.button}
               onPress={() => setMood(mood)}>
               <Text style={styles.answer}>{mood}</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
        }
      </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
               disabled={currentMood.length !== 0}
               style={styles.button}
               onPress={() => alert("mood:", currentMood)}>
               <Text>Submit</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the very detailed solution! When I click select the alert gives me `mood:` with nothing after it, which means that the `mood` variable must be blank. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-grass-sruu0?file=/src/index.js   
check out this sandbox, I think this should solve your problem. Let me know, if otherwise.

Comment: @smilada Where do you call saveData? Its not listed in your code.

Comment: @AshishSingh I'll look at it, thank you!
@Domino987 it's another `TouchableOpacity` where `onPress={this.saveData}`

Comment: I added the "" when I was plugging your solution into my code. It did not work

Comment: Can you put the code in a sandbox and share it here? Like the whole component? As you have it right now?

Comment: You forgot the "" around sad happy etc in the setState onPress.

Comment: `onPress={() => this.setState({mood: 'excited'})}` has the '' which is = to ""

Comment: Can you console log the mood in the render function to see if it changes.

Comment: Can you show the current selected mood as text in your tree?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that :( and would appreciate if you can just edit it and let me know what's wrong.

Comment: I will take a look later and come back to you.

Comment: @smilada The problem was the alert. You cannot put the mood as seconds argument but concat the first: https://snack.expo.io/BczwTq1bC

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if this was to used for a react application or react native application but I have prepared a code sandbox basis the code you have shared above.

I have made use of setState callback function to have the most updated state value to be shown in the alert browser call.

And have used the current state value in render to conditionally modify click as well as display/style behaviour for selected mood/button.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-grass-sruu0?file=/src/index.js) is the codesandbox link. Upvote/let me know if this solved your issue.